# Read from spreadsheets with different number of sheets in each

Tags: r, excel

I use the following code to read a series of spreadsheets into R. However, then I found that even though data in all spreadsheets shares the same header and structure, some spreadsheets have more than one sheet. For example, in one spreadsheet, there are two sheets each containing some data. My question is how to modify my code to read data from all sheets without openning each spreadsheet to find out how many sheets are in it. Thanks.

```
library(readxl)

files <- Sys.glob("*.xlsx")
files

PL <- read_excel(files[1], col_names=TRUE)

for(i in 2:length(files)){

  x <- read_excel(files[i], col_names=TRUE)
  PL <- rbind(PL, x)
  print(i)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `excel_sheets` of the `readxl` package:

```
> library(readxl)
> sheets <- excel_sheets("xlsx_datasets.xlsx")
> sheets
[1] "iris"     "mtcars"   "chickwts" "quakes"  
> x <- read_excel("xlsx_datasets.xlsx", sheet=sheets[1])
```

That is, to read all your files:

```
PL <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(files)){
  sheets <- excel_sheets(files[i])
  for(sheet in sheets){
    x <- read_excel(files[i], col_names=TRUE, sheet=sheet)
    PL <- rbind(PL, x)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `tidyverse` you can use `purrr` to iterate

```
# you could use library(tidyverse) too which includes these two packages and more 
library(readxl)
library(purrr) # for function map and set_names below 
list_xl <-  map(files, 
    ~.x %>% 
        excel_sheets() %>% 
        set_names() %>% 
        map(read_excel, path = .x))
```

`excel_sheet` gives you the names of the sheet in your files. You don't have to know how many. Then you name those sheets. After you iterate on each sheet to read it with `read_excel`. 
At the beginning, `purrr::map` applies on `files` let's you iterate on each file to do previous process.

At the end, you obtain a list of list. You could again use `tidyverse` package to put the result in the form you want to deal with it afterwards.

You could find great example on the [readxl website workflow page](http://readxl.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/readxl-workflows.html)